# Display y axis value horizontal line drawn In bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am using (matplotlib.pyplot as plt) matplotlib to draw a bar chart. On that bar chart I have drawn a horizontal line using axhline() function in grey colour . I want that the point (value on y axis = 42000) from where that horizontal line starts should also display the value i.e 42000 . What to do?

This is my current image:

[image]

On the image below, see the '39541.52' point? I want to display exactly like that on my image and my point value is '42000'

[image]

Comment: I think I have already provided [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876219/point-picker-event-handler-drawing-line-and-displaying-coordinates-in-matplotlib) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133017/how-to-change-colors-automatically-once-a-parameter-is-changed) on the exact same problem sheet. If you include your code and state exactly where the problem is, we can surely help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A label can be created e.g. using `ax.text()`. To position the label a nice trick is to use a transform that allows to use axes coordinates for the x position and data coordinates for the y position.

```
ax.text(1.02, 4.2e4, "42000", .. , transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = np.array([34,40,38,50])*1e3
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(30e3, 60e3)
ax.bar(x,y, color=plt.cm.plasma_r(norm(y)) )
ax.axhline(4.2e4, color="gray")
ax.text(1.02, 4.2e4, "42000", va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5),
        transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
plt.show()
```

[image]