# matplotlib: reduce axes width in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, colorbar, colormap

I have a matplotlib bar chart, which bars are colored according to some rules through a colormap. I need a colorbar on the right of the main axes, so I added a new axes with

```
fig, (ax, ax_cbar) = plt.subplots(1,2)
```

and managed to draw my color bar in the ax_bar axes, while I have my data displayed in the ax axes. Now I need to reduce the width of the ax_bar, because it looks like this:
[image]

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subplots` will always divide your figure equally.  You can manually divide up your figure in a number of ways.  My preferred method is using `subplot2grid`.

In this example, we are setting the figure to have 1 row and 10 columns.  We then set `ax` to be the start at row,column = (0,0) and have a width of 9 columns.  Then set `ax_cbar` to start at (0,9) and has by default a width of 1 column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

num_columns = 10
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,num_columns), (0,0), colspan=num_columns-1)
ax_cbar = plt.subplot2grid((1,num_columns), (0,num_columns-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The ususal way to add a colorbar is by simply putting it next to the axes:

```
fig.colorbar(sm)
```

where `fig` is the figure and `sm` is the scalar mappable to which the colormap refers. In the case of the bars, you need to create this `ScalarMappable` yourself. Apart from that there is no need for complex creation of multiple axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

fig , ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0,1,2,3]
y = np.array([34,40,38,50])*1e3
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(30e3, 60e3)
ax.bar(x,y, color=plt.cm.plasma_r(norm(y)) )
ax.axhline(4.2e4, color="gray")
ax.text(0.02, 4.2e4, "42000", va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=1),
        transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.plasma_r, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

fig.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you do want to create a special axes for the colorbar yourself, the easiest method would be to set the width already inside the call to  `subplots`:

```
fig , (ax, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, gridspec_kw={"width_ratios" : [10,1]})
```

and later put the colorbar to the `cax` axes,

```
fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
```

---

Note that the following questions have been asked for this homework assignment already:

- [Point picker event_handler drawing line and displaying coordinates in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876219/point-picker-event-handler-drawing-line-and-displaying-coordinates-in-matplotlib)
- [Matplotlib's widget to select y-axis value and change barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369396/matplotlibs-widget-to-select-y-axis-value-and-change-barplot)
- [Display y axis value horizontal line drawn In bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560801/display-y-axis-value-horizontal-line-drawn-in-bar-chart)
- [How to change colors automatically once a parameter is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133017/how-to-change-colors-automatically-once-a-parameter-is-changed)
- [Interactively Re-color Bars in Matplotlib Bar Chart using Confidence Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642990/interactively-re-color-bars-in-matplotlib-bar-chart-using-confidence-intervals)

Comment: Was using `width_ratios` with multiple seaboard heat maps. There, I guess this is the easiest approach. Excellent answer.